# For loop for curling on multiple pages with API's

Tags: shell, shell-script, curl

I am trying to crawl a website for fetching pages using an API. When I issue the command

```
cd desktop/mysite ; curl -O https://api.mysite.com/info?page=2
```

I get the data on the desktop. Then I wanted to loop for pages say 2 to 100. I am unable to get the json files on to my desktop. Can someone correct my code?

```bsh
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do 
    cd desktop/mysite
    curl -O https://api.mysite.com/info?page=i
done
```

Comment: Use `page=$i` instead of `page=i`.

Comment: According to the [curl manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), you can do this using without a for loop, just curl: `cd desktop/mysite && curl --remote-name-all "https://api.mysite.com/info?page=[1-100]"`

Comment: I need to curl with an Oauth authentication in that case how do i specify with a token  curl -O "https://api.mysite.com/info?page=[1=100]&accesstoken=xyz" because it is not taking the token

Comment: We can't help you because we have no idea what site you are using or how it works.

Comment: I am not familiar with how that site works. See what you can find out by yourself and then post a separate question if you still need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$i` instead of `i`. The former gets replaced with the value of `i`, while the latter is mere text.

```
cd desktop/mysite # If this is invariant then it does not need to be in the loop
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do
  curl -O "https://api.mysite.com/info?page=$i"
done
```

Comment: Nice invariant comment...

Answer (score 5):

You can also let curl iterate over a numeric range like this:

```
curl -O 'https://api.mysite.com/info?page=[1-100]'
```